# Best way to deliver real time information?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, json

I currently have three screens showing a web page with information taken from a database. This information gets updated every 10 seconds. These three screens call AJAX on a PHP script that does a MySQL query that prints JSON encoded results, and that's what it uses to represent the data. The query is a pretty resource intensive one.

My problem has to do with scalability: If ten people were to enter that page, they would all be making the php script to run at the same time and every 10 seconds, thus overloading the server.

I'm considering doing this query on the background and outputting the results to a text file and then retrieve that text file via AJAX, but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

So the question is: How do I deal with repetitive and very slow sql queries to allow access for multiple users?

Comment: Are you sure that is the right question? If you use nodejs with socket.io, you can easily send the data when it updates (and not ask every 10sec if it did) and even group the users

Comment: Are you already using any type of caching such as Memcached or Redis ? Because that may be a possible solution.

Comment: How "intensive" is your resource intensive query? A single request per second should not be a problem for your Database Server...

Comment: I wasn't really sure what the correct question was, because I realized late that it was all about bad design. No, I'm not currently using Memcached, but will look into it. However, it seems like nodejs with socket.io is the best solution for this case. Thanks for the quick answers!